# Calculate the cost of the pen to the nearest cent

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

A merchant sold a pen for $\$6.90$, thereby making a profit of $15\%$ on her cost calculate the cost of the pen to the merchant to the nearest cent.

---

So I know the merchant made a $15\%$ profit on the pen, so she bought it for a cheaper price. To find the cost of the pen before I have to take the price now, $\$6.90$ and times it by $85\%$, this gives $\$5.87$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Is this answer right?  
So I know the merchant made a 15% profit on the pen, so she bought it for a cheaper price. To find the cost of the pen before I have to take the price now, $6.90 and times it by 85%. So 6.90x.85= 5.865 which rounds to $5.87

Answer (score 0):

If there is a 15% profit, that means that 6.90 was 115% of the original price. What would 100% of the price be?

Comment: I don't know percentages so I have no idea... I'm just now starting to learn them

Answer (score 0):

If we call the price $p$, You know that $1.15\times p = 6.90$ so you would need to solve this equation for $p$ by dividing each side by $1.15$ giving you $p = \frac{6.90}{1.15} = \$6$

Comment: Thank you! But where did you got the 1.15 from?

Comment: 1.15 multiplied by something is the same as 115% (see previous answer) of something. So 115% of 20 is the same as 1.15 x 20. The reason for this is contained in the meaning of the % symbol. It means "per cent", i.e. out of one hundred. 115 "out of one hundred" is 115/100 is 1.15. So 115% **of** 20 is 1.15 **times** 20.

Comment: Oh. Okay. I got this... :) Oh my god, it's a little but easier now. Thank you very much!